Why does xbindkeys not get the thumbwheel mouse buttons of Logitech MX Master anymore?
The action I configured for the thumbwheel is applied when I enter xbindkeys -k and turn the wheel inside the window.
However, when I turn that mouse wheel anywhere else, nothing happens. I restart xbindkeys by runnings xbindkeys after killall xbindkeys.
I think recently it had some problems but usually turning the thumbwheel worked. When quitting that process and running xbindkeys -n there is no error message. Turning the thumbwheel anywhere while one xbindkey process is running according to the System Monitor does not have an effect. It does not make a difference whether solaar is running or not. I also tried restarting the plasmashell. xbindkeys -k does not show anything when entering the thumbwheel (only when entering a keyboard key) but that is probably normal.
How to get this to work, what else could I try to make xbindkeys get the mousewheel turning input again?
It works when xbindkeys-config is running and the mouse is inside it after pressing Apply but not anywhere else. Under Edit -> View generated rc file the file matches exactly the default config file at /home/username/.xbindkeysrc it still does not work after quitting xbindkeys-config or after running killall -HUP xbindkeys. I then did run xbindkeys --file /home/username/.xbindkeysrc -v and it showed the below error too even after running the killall command a few times it doesn't show that error and shows the correct config that's in .xbindkeysrc. It still doesn't work.

Previously, I had the problem that xbindkeys-config did not start anymore and xbindkeys -n returned
*** Warning ***
Please verify that there is not another program running
which captures one of the keys captured by xbindkeys.
It seems that there is a conflict, and xbindkeys can't
grab all the keys defined in its configuration file.

I solved problem 1 by opening up /home/username/.xbindkeysrc in a text editor and commenting out everything and then recreating that file by loading one of the saved profiles in xbindkeys-config but changing its settings by entering the configured key again (turning the thumbwheel) which now seems to be a bit different than before. Maybe that is because of some upgrade.
I solved problem 2 with sudo killall xbindkeys. Maybe reconnecting with solaar helped.

Which version of debian/KDE and in which mode (X.org/Wayland) are you using at the moment and which version have you been used previously?
I assume, that you have been using X.org previously and that you are now using wayland sessions. With wayland xbindkeys cannot be used anymore, because wayland has a completely different architecture which prevents not-focussed applications to receive keyboard and mouse-inputs (which is nice for security).
You should have a look at input-remapper which I use since years on wayland to remap my forward-/back button on the mouse to CTRL+Pg-Up/-Down to be able to switch Tabs with them. There is also a debian-package for it with a nice GUI. It utilizes a privileged service in the background to create a fake-input device and to capture the inputs of your actual device without breaking the security brought you by wayland.

I'm using Debian 12 with Wayland and I've used Wayland for quite some time so it did work with Wayland. Is there something else that makes these xbindkeys things work in wayland? I wonder why it kept working after switching to Wayland. I will try input-remapper.

I'm clueless as to why xbindkeys kept working long after upgrading to Debian 12 and Wayland. Maybe it was a recent upgrade (it only shows v 12) cat /proc/version shows Linux version 5.10.0-17-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc-10 (Debian 10.2.1-6). So I did run sudo apt-get remove xbindkeys xbindkeys-config and sudo apt-get install input-remapper-gtk then configured the mousewheel & check "Autoload". It works so this is solved. I can only configure keyboard presses but not commands like I could with xbindkeys but I simply changed the setting of what the key press does.

It's at version 12.7 as could be seen via cat /etc/debian_version. Asked about why gcc-10 was used separately here.
